# Error while decrypting symmetric in java (android) with RSA

Tags: java, android, encryption, encryption-asymmetric

I am trying to use asymmetric encryption on Android using JCE, the problem is that when I am deciphering the bytes I return in a string they are null.
I can only return a string because I'm connected to a JavaScript server, which is why methods always return strings.
The problem is that RSA Decrypt returns a null String.
All other things are working and encoding / decoding with Base64 works well.
Any idea what's failing?
Thank you!

```
public class AsymetricUtil{

private static final String KEYMODE = "RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding";
private KeyPairGenerator kpg;
private KeyPair kp;
private PublicKey publicKey;
private PublicKey publicKeyOther = null;
private PrivateKey privateKey;
private byte [] encryptedBytes,decryptedBytes;
private Cipher cipher;

public AsymetricUtil(){
    try{
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance(KEYMODE);
        generateKeys();
    }catch( NoSuchPaddingException| NoSuchAlgorithmException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


public void setPublicKey(String key) {

    byte[] data = Base64.decode(key, Base64.NO_WRAP);
    X509EncodedKeySpec spec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(data);
    KeyFactory fact;

    try {
        fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        this.publicKeyOther = fact.generatePublic(spec);

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public String RSAEncrypt(final String plain) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKeyOther);
    encryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(plain.getBytes("Utf-8"));
    return Base64.encodeToString(encryptedBytes, Base64.NO_WRAP);
}


public String RSADecrypt(final String encryptedStr) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
    decryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(Base64.decode(encryptedStr, Base64.NO_WRAP));
    return new String(decryptedBytes);
}

public void generateKeys() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
    kpg.initialize(1024);
    kp = kpg.genKeyPair();
    publicKey = kp.getPublic();
    privateKey = kp.getPrivate();
}


/**
 * Convert publicKey to String
 *
 * @return  {String}
 */
public String getKey(){
    return Base64.encodeToString(publicKey.getEncoded(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
}
```

Comment: What have you done to debug. Provide more information and a [mcve].

Comment: `return new String(decryptedBytes);` should be `return new String(decryptedBytes, "UTF-8");`

Comment: The String that i return in RSA Decrypt is always null. And i tried with the UTF-8 and the string still's being null.